# undefined reference when linking V8

Tags: c++, linker, g++, linker-errors, v8

I'm strugling to compile a really small example with V8..

cpp program is this:

```
#include "v8.h"

int main()
{
     v8::HandleScope handle_scope;

     return 0;
}
```

Compile line: g++ -I/home/lterje/git/tengine/Externals/v8/include /home/lterje/git/tengine/Externals/v8/out/ia32.release/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_snapshot.a test.cpp -o test -lpthread

Error I'm getting:

```
/tmp/ccHYtJuE.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::HandleScope()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x22): undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::~HandleScope()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What exactly is the difference between the base, snapshot and no snapshot library files? I've tried linking with each of them, but none of them works :/

Comment: how do you link againest these libraries? do you have a CMakeLists.txt file?can you include that

Comment: https://developers.google.com/v8/get_started If you look at the bottom there and point 3, it seams like you can just give the full path like they do there?

Comment: You need to download and install the v8 libraries and if you installed them on a defuault path, like /usr/local/lib etc... then it sufficies to link againest them using -llibv8 or -lv8 or something. did you do that?

Comment: as you see from the compile line I've downloaded it into a folder and I've built it with gyp.. they're not linking to v8 on the link I posted above? I don't even think libv8 exists anymore.. its libv8_base.a , libv8_snapshot.a and libv8_nosnapshot.a as I mentioned above.. have you built it before and if so, what is the line you are building with?

Comment: sorry I never used v8 I only know about c++ compilation. and from what I can see here is that your program included the right header(i.e. he looks for that header inside local folder and default include paths) but you never instructed him on how to link againest these headers or include the lib/.so in a local path otherwise he has noway of finding the header. where is the v8.so located on your machine?

Comment: if you are under linux try on the console before compiling: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:PATH_TO_V8LIB where PATH_TO_V8 is your installation directory of v8

Comment: there is no .so file.. theres nothing about it on the link I pasted or on https://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/BuildingWithGYP ..

Comment: which "make" did you use? what system do you have? did you follow the optional steps?

Comment: I'm build the shared now, but its really wierd that its not mentioned that you should do so in the getting started guide.. I'll try that though

Comment: it is not uncommon that a help guide is wrong or missing details you know.

Comment: You're not following the instructions. The `.a` files need to go _after_ your source files on the command line.

Comment: Mat: I've tried changing that around with no luck.. it worked linking with the .so file instead :) Moataz, if you wrap it up into an answer I'll accept it..

Answer (score 2):

first I have to say sorry for my poor english.
I have just link the .a file to my own project.
There's ld error because of the dependencies of the libv8_snapshot.a is not been given.

This is my compile statement:

g++ -o xxxxx -I ~v8/out/native/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_{base.native,snapshot}.a ~v8/out/native/obj.target/third_party/icu/libicu{data,i18n,snapshot}.a ~v8/out/native/obj.target/icudata/third_party/icu/linux/icudt46_dat.o -lrt -lpthread

I think that the libv8_base.native.a libv8_snapshot.a is dependend on icu and icudt46 files and thereis some functions about  unix clock_time is dependend on "rt", so add "-lrt"

Hope helpful for you all~
As a Chinese,sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

> Compile line:
>   g++ -I/home/lterje/git/tengine/Externals/v8/include /home/lterje/git/tengine/Externals/v8/out/ia32.release/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_snapshot.a test.cpp -o test -lpthread

This link line is incorrect. Try this instead:

```
g++ -I/home/lterje/git/tengine/Externals/v8/include \
  test.cpp -o test \
  /home/.../obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_snapshot.a \
  -lpthread
```

Read [this](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html) to understand why the order matters.