# How to link against v8?

Tags: c++, compilation, v8, static-linking

I successfully compiled [v8 javascript engine](https://developers.google.com/v8/) (on windows) ; now I try to follow the [Getting started article](https://developers.google.com/v8/get_started) but I am stuck at this point:

3. Compile hello_world.cpp, linking to the static libraries created in the build process.

The example is for linux (and probably for an earlier version).

I tried to link against all libraries that I could without success:

```
User@PC:/cygdrive/c/Users/Yvain/Documents/depot_tools/v8/build/Release
g++  -std=c++0x  -I"C:\Users\Yvain\Documents\depot_tools\v8" -Llib -lv8_libbase -lv8_base_0 -lv8_base_1 -lv8_base_2 -lv8_base_3 -lgmock -lgtest -licui18n -licuuc -lv8_external_snapshot -lv8_libplatform -lv8_nosnapshot hello_world.cpp -o hello_world
```

It gives the following errors:

```
  /tmp/ccPxkjlV.o:hello_world.cpp:(.text+0x1a): 
       undefined reference to « v8::V8::InitializeICU(char const*) »
  [...]undefined reference to « v8::V8::InitializeExternalStartupData(char const*) »
  [...]
  [...]undefined reference to  « v8::Isolate::Exit() »
```

There is a working example: `v8/sample/hello-world.vcxproj` but I don't understand where the libraries are specified in the project.

Comment: [Please explain why you vote down](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes) when you do.

Comment: Have you been through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)?

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15071432/undefined-reference-when-linking-v8) as well

Comment: There is a working example: `v8/sample/hello-world.vcxproj` but I don't understand where the libraries are specified in the project.

Comment: Since your prompt contains "/cygdrive" I assume this is all using Cygwin tools. Does the -I"C:\Users..." really work? Why not -I/cygdrive/c/Users..." ?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio project `v8/sample/hello-world.vcxproj` has been generated with GYP from `v8/build/samples/samples.gyp` with all necessary dependencies.

In the current version of "Getting started" article, in "Run example" section, item list #3 contains an example of command line to build the hello_world:

> Compile hello_world.cpp, linking to the static libraries created in
>   the build process. For example, on 64bit Linux using the GNU compiler:

```
g++ -I. hello_world.cpp -o hello_world -Wl,--start-group out/x64.release/obj.target/{tools/gyp/libv8_{base,libbase,external_snapshot,libplatform},third_party/icu/libicu{uc,i18n,data}}.a -Wl,--end-group -lrt -ldl -pthread -std=c++0x
```

On Windows you need to use the similar list of static libraries as a linker input. Please note these static libraries are placed in `v8/build/Release/lib` directory.

Comment: I read that, but I don't have the proper files in `out/x64.release/obj.target/` (I just have a file `out\x64.release\obj.target\third_party\icu\icudata.stamp` and an empty dir`out\x64.release\obj.target\v8_base\src`).